# Crear rectangulo hueco java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio que me pide hacer un rectángulo hueco hecho con asteriscos, de tal forma que la altura y la anchura es introducida por teclado.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la altura");
        int alt = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce la anchura");
        int anch = sc.nextInt();
        String aux = "*";
        for (int i = 0; i < alt-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(aux);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < anch; j++) {
            System.out.print(aux + " ");
        }
}
```

Consigo que imprima el lado izquierdo y la base pero no sé como hacer el resto

Comment: El codigo de la base es el mismo que el de la parte de arriba pero en otra linea. Y para los lados, tienes que dibujar dos asteriscos, dejando una separacion de espacios entre ellos igual a la anchura

Answer (score 0):

Quizás es mejor "averiguar" primero que carácter escribir...
Si el asterisco (*) o el blanco ( )
Y luego al final de cada bucle de linea escribir un salto de linea.

Algo así... (Puedes adaptarlo como quieras)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangulo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la altura: ");
        int altura = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce la anchura: ");
        int anchura = sc.nextInt();
        String aux = "";
        // Imprimir
        for (int alto = 0; alto < altura; alto++) {
            for (int largo = 0; largo < anchura; largo++) {
                // Primera y Ultima Linea (Todo con *)
                if (alto==0 | alto == altura-1) {
                        aux="*";                    
                } else {
                // Zona media (* o blanco)
                    if (largo == 0 | largo == anchura-1) aux="*";
                    if (largo !=0 & largo != anchura-1) aux=" ";
                }
                // Pintamos caracter que corresponda
                System.out.print(aux);
                // Si es final de linea un salto
                if (largo == anchura-1) System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil poner fuera del bucle interior un `System.out.println()`? Te ahorras una comparación, y así es mas fácil de leer

Comment: Totalmente correcto. Simplemente era para "explicación" de la logica del programa.

Answer (score 0):

La misma gata pero revolcada y más ágil para rectángulos grandes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RectanguloHueco {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la altura: ");
        int altura = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce la anchura: ");
        int anchura = sc.nextInt();

        StringBuilder sbInterior = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbExterior = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < anchura; i++) {
            sbExterior.append("*");
            sbInterior.append((i == 0 || i == anchura - 1) ? "*" : " ");
        }
        String exterior = sbExterior.toString();
        String interior = sbInterior.toString();

        for (int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
            System.out.println((i == 0 || i == altura - 1) ? exterior : interior);
        }
    }
}
```